# Determine "normal" Users from User Collection loaded with CSOM (provider-hosted App)

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, user, provider-hosted-app

In my provider-hosted app I load the UserCollection from SharePoint by CSOM (Client Side Object Model), like this:

```
UserCollection users = web.SiteUsers;
clientContext.Load<UserCollection>(users);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I only want "normal" users to be displayed in my app. The result given here also shows users which seem to be system users, like:

- _SPOCacheFull
- System Account
- Everyone
- Everyone except external users

How can I determine if a user is a normal site user or a system user?

I checked the groups but most of the system users don't have any groups. Also the email is mostly empty but not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.user(v=office.15).aspx) properties could be used for that purpose:

- [Principal.PrincipalType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.principal.principaltype(v=office.15).aspx) - `PrincipalType.User`
  value specifies a **user** as the principal type
- [UserIdInfo.NameIdIssuer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.useridinfo.nameidissuer(v=office.15).aspx) - configuration-agnostic
  reference to the type of the name identifier issuer, for SPO users its value: `urn:federation:microsoftonline`

The below example demonstrates how to determine a "regular" users in [Web.SiteUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.siteusers(v=office.15).aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<User> LoadUsers(ClientContext context)
{
   var users = context.LoadQuery(context.Web.SiteUsers.Where(u => u.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.User && u.UserId.NameIdIssuer == "urn:federation:microsoftonline"));
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   return users;
}
```

Comment: Ah very nice! The urn:federation:microsoftonline Value is indeed very helpful as most of the SharePoint System users have PrincipalType.User aswell.